# Small BM25+ implementation for probibalistic result ranking

Tags: ruby, search

I came up with this small implementation of an [Okapi BM25+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25#Modifications) ranker using Ruby. I cooked it up in a very short time so it's very simple but I'm trying to think whether there's a better way to write it. In particular, I'm wondering if I should have something like a `Ranker` class -- intuitively I feel as though I should but it seems to work fine this way too.

The two classes used are `Document` and `Collection`. A `Collection` can contain many `Document`s. Very simple.

**document.rb**

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :body, :rank

  def initialize(params={:body=>'', :rank=>nil})
    @body = params[:body]
    @rank = params[:rank]
  end

  def length
    @body.length
  end

  def include?(term)
    @body.include?(term)
  end

  def term_freq(term)
    # Will need something better here to clean out the document.
    # This is temporary ;)
   @body.gsub(/[^\s\p{Alnum}\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Hangul}]/,'')
    .downcase
    .split
    .count(term) 
  end
end
```

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection

  def initialize(params={:docs=>[], :query=>nil})
    @docs = params[:docs]
    @query = params[:query]
  end

  def containing_term(term)
    total = 0
    @docs.each do |doc|
      total += 1 if doc.include?(term) 
    end
    total
  end

  def avg_dl
    doc_lengths = 0
    @docs.each do |doc|
      doc_lengths += doc.length
    end
    doc_lengths / total_docs
  end

  def total_docs
    @docs.size
  end

  def idf(term)
    numerator = total_docs - containing_term(term) + 0.5
    denominator = containing_term(term) + 0.5
    Math.log(numerator / denominator)
  end

  def bm25(params={:k => 1.2, :b => 0.75, :delta => 1.0})
    @k = params[:k]
    @b = params[:b]
    @delta = params[:delta]

    @docs.each do |doc|
      score = 0
      dl = doc.length
      query_terms = @query.split

      query_terms.each do |term|
        dtf = doc.term_freq(term)
        numerator = dtf * (@k + 1)
        denominator = dtf + @k * (1 - @b + @b * (doc.length / avg_dl))
        score += idf(term) * (numerator/denominator) + @delta
      end
      doc.rank = score
    end
    @docs
  end

  def sort_by_rank
    @docs.sort! {|a, b| a.rank <=> b.rank}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use built-ins to simplify the code:

```
def containing_term(term)
  total = 0
  @docs.each do |doc|
    total += 1 if doc.include?(term) 
   end
 total
end
```

Becomes:

```
def containing_term(term)
  @docs.count {|doc| doc.include?(term) }
end
```

And

```
def avg_dl
  doc_lengths = 0
  @docs.each do |doc|
    doc_lengths += doc.length
  end
  doc_lengths / total_docs
end
```

Becomes:

```
def avg_dl
  @docs.map(&:length).inject(:+) / total_docs
end
```

**You are close to immutable,  make the last step**

In `Collection` you use `sort!`, disallowing method chaining, `sort` and returning a new object would be more expected.

**Use a Hash for an easy but massive optimization**

The method:

```
def term_freq(term)
   # Will need something better here to clean out the document.
   # This is temporary ;)
  @body.gsub(/[^\s\p{Alnum}\p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Hangul}]/,'')
   .downcase
   .split
   .count(term) 
end
```

Should be a Hash lookup, where the Hash is created at init time, time complexity would become O(1) with an Hash instead of O(n).

Comment: Just another thing though, as per my question: does it intuitively make sense to have a `Ranker` object that interacts with `Collection` or is it useless? I'm just trying to think as Object Oriented as possible :P

Comment: @DaniG2k I am not sure, ruby encourages objects, but the Document class has only one method that "does work". Also remember that methods are allowed to be stand-alone in Ruby, so don't feel forced to use classes.

Comment: @DaniG2k I must say that the code is very readable, so classes seem like the right choice for this problem.